# Does this mean my model is useless?

Tags: machine-learning, standard-deviation, measurement-error

Long story short, I have a random forest I've created. It's mean absolute error is .209 for the test set.

The (scaled) standard deviation of the y column is .201 (for all the y column data, not just test set).

I have a decent grasp of statistics, but I'm not sure if this means that my model is basically worse than just taking a random value +/- .2 from the mean of the y column? Or has my scaling made these values incomparable? The *actual* SD of the y column is 4.388494.

Shouldn't MAE be lower than SD?

Some explanation, hopefully intuitive, as to why that's not necessarily true (if I'm wrong) would be appreciated, or an answer for the general case if I shouldn't be comparing the scaled sd to my MAE.

Comment: How did you scale? I a range between [0,1]? But in general you cannot compare values with two different units. That is like saying: My apple weighs 100 gram and the elephant weighs 3 tons. But 100>3 so why is the apple heavier than the elephant.

Comment: SD is not compareable to MAE. If you want to get a baseline model, build a model with only the intercept / constant, and compare this model MAE with yours.